# How to automatiaclly load view from parent XIB file in UIViewController subclass?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, xib

Assume `SomeViewController` being a subclass of `BaseViewController`.

Calling `BaseViewController()` automatically loads the view from `BaseViewController.xib`.

Calling `SomeViewController()` will automatically look for `SomeViewController.xib` and will fail if this file is not available.

Of course one could use `SomeViewController(nibName: "BaseViewController", bundle: nil))` but this is not very handy.

Is there some way to automatically fall back to the parents XIB file if there is not XIB file for the child class?

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit

class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    // Your code for BaseViewController
}

class SomeViewController: BaseViewController {
    convenience init() {
        // Attempt to load the XIB file for SomeViewController
        if let nibName = NSStringFromClass(self).components(separatedBy: ".").last {
            if Bundle.main.path(forResource: nibName, ofType: "nib") != nil {
                self.init(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil)
            } else {
                // If SomeViewController.xib doesn't exist, fallback to BaseViewController.xib
                self.init(nibName: "BaseViewController", bundle: nil)
            }
        } else {
            // Fallback to BaseViewController.xib if there's an issue with the class name
            self.init(nibName: "BaseViewController", bundle: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

There isn't a built-in mechanism in UIKit that automatically falls back to a parent's XIB file if a child's XIB file is missing.
When you create an instance of a view controller, it will look for a XIB file with the same name as the class by default.